# Run javascript from external location after jQuery(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, external, document-ready

An external javascript loads like this in a div in the page content:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/example.js"></script>
```

The external script prints a sign up form for newsletter, like this:

```
document.write("<body>\n<form method=\"post\" action ETC....");
```

The problem is that the external server is slow and this third party script loads before jQuery(document).ready(), which deleays slideshows facebook plugins etc.

**How can I make this script to render at it´s current position in the page content after the entire page has loaded?**

(I have tried lot´s of suggested sollutions in different threads, but none worked for me...)

Comment: If you won't explain and demonstrate what exactly you've tried and how it failed, you're likely to get the same answers.

Comment: just put the document write inside the ready?

Comment: Since the external script is creating the `<body>` element, how can yo display anything before it's loaded?

Comment: A third-party script that prints the `<body>` tags? Put it into an iframe.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(window).load` it will be triggered after all the files/assets being downloaded.

```
$(window).load(function () {
  // run code
});
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I run a script from an external location which outputs with document.write?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is "inject" the script one the page has loaded:

```
$(function () {
     $('body').append('<script src="example.com/script.js"></script>');
});
```

This will execute on document ready but it's not a problem since the script will be loaded asynchronously.

Comment: a) no reason to wait with async loading for ready b) this does not work with the script above since it uses `document.write`

Comment: This did not work with the script! This won´t make the output render where in the code the script is called, will it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onload="RunScript();">

function RunScript()
{
   document.write("<body>\n<form method=\"post\" action ETC....");
}
```

or

```
document.onload=function ...
```

Comment: There is no function to call. As you see this script is renderd where it is called with document.write.

Comment: @Turbojohan in your onload function of RunScript() you can render html as in my updated answer

Comment: I see, but how do I call the script from an external location?